# AnyLogic Pickup/Combine/Assemble

Tags: anylogic

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VV3BO.png)I am looking to model and assembly line where a box stops at a station, has a few parts put into it, the box travels down the station to the next operator to have more parts, and then it's sealed and put on a pallet. I'm struggling to have AnyLogic seize my operator for the steps after the box arrives at the first station. I want that same operator to do every part at station 1, at which point another operator would fill the fox at station 2. This conveyor is also not powered, so I don't know if this can be represented some how.

I am very new to AnyLogic (just basic training) and I have limited coding knowledge. I have tried all of the boxes I can think of (batch/pickup/assembler/seize) to try to make this happen.

Comment: Welcome to SOF. This place works best for you if you ask very focused, specific questions on 1 AnyLogic issue, show exactly what you tried already and where you are stuck. If you want to know “how do I best do X in AnyLogic”, you should use the LinkedIn forum instead. Check this overview to the community to understand why: https://benjamin-schumann.com/blog/anylogic-community. Else, try to break down your broad question into specific sub-questions and ask them separately, see https://benjamin-schumann.com/blog/anylogic-stackoverflow. Welcome again, happy to help